# Docusign implementation for laravel/php

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi

I have a few questions regarding the docusign api. First of all, I want to build an application, where users can sign a document, through docusign.
My questions are, is the OAuth token required for all the api calls? I have found a package where I add my email, password, and app_id, and I can make api requests, envelopes, etc.
Second, do my clients need to have a docusign account? If I build the envelope and the response view, if I don’t add a client_user_id, the url that i receive, redirects me to my pdf, but I cannot sign.
Can someone help me out with some information, and the best alternative?

Comment: And if I have to use OAuth token, do I have to ask every user for consent?

Comment: I also need to say that, there will be a main account, with a template PDF, that will get info prefilled, and users will only sign, and I have to keep a copy of every envelope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [create a developer accoun](https://go.docusign.com/o/sandbox/?ga=2.70927056.1363819232.1590515244-192278368.1546193875&ECID=20890&elqCampaignId=20890&LS=NA_DEV_BOTH_BetaSite_2020-05&utm_campaign=NA_DEV_BOTH_BetaSite_2020-05&Channel=DDCUS000016968056&cName=DocuSign.com)t, for free, where you can try out and use all functionality and build your app. You can later promote it to production.
You will need an auth token for every call.
I recommend to start with this code example - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php and use either Auth Code Grant or JWT for authentication.
You will need to create an integration key and set it up so you can get auth tokens.
But you have to have a token for every API call, that is correct.
As for consent, it's only needed one per DocuSign user. Not per user of your app. The users of your app could be different, but you make all API calls via the same one that consented.
So, yes, the users only sign, they don't need a DocuSign account.

Comment: I have done almost all the above. I also have a question regarding this: I set up an envelope and the signer a user of my website. If the person has a docusign account, he would see the completed document in his docusign account?

Comment: It will be done using your account, but they would have access to it. (by that, I mean for that particular envelope, they can see it, not access to the account).

Comment: ok. so I've successfully created a flow where I can refresh the access token everytime I want. I build an envelope, a viewRequest, and I get a url for my user to sign. After he signs, I would like to know if I can send him a copy, if possible, and my main question right now is : I've created a template with many text and checkbox inputs, they are required. If I have information about the user that signs the pdf, I would like to put it into the PDF but also lock the input, disable it. Is it possible?

Comment: yes, possible. If you don't mind, you have different questions, ask them in separate threads. Mark this as answered, if you original question was answered and add another one if you don't mind.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for helping me out